# How to permit parameters to rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am using a angularjs and rails. I want to upload a song in my application

below is my JSON data of uploaded song using angularjs

```
{
 "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f20ec024608 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151106-6349-1impdro.mp3>,
  @original_filename="01 - 2 States - Offo [DJMaza.Info].mp3", 
  @content_type="audio/mp3", 
  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"01 - 2 States - Offo [DJMaza.Info].mp3\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/mp3\r\n">, 
  "event_id"=>"19"
}
```

but the i am not getting correct parameters in my controllers

```
class Api::V1::PlaylistsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @playlist = @event.playlists.create(:file)
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  end

end
```

I have events in my application and an event contains many songs.

but it gives me the following error

```
ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.):
app/controllers/api/v1/playlists_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

below is my angular view and controller

```
<div ng-controller="SongController">
    <input type="file" nv-file-select uploader="uploader"/><br/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
            Name: <span ng-bind="item.file.name"></span><br/>
            <button ng-click="item.upload()">upload</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


.controller('SongController', ['$scope','FileUploader','$stateParams',function($scope, FileUploader,$stateParams) {

    $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({url: '/events/'+$stateParams.id+'/playlists'});

}]);
```

playlist model

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  mount_uploader :file, SongUploader
end
```

playlist schema

```
  create_table "playlists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "song",       limit: 255
    t.integer  "event_id",   limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end
```

I am using carrierwave to upload in rails.

Comment: Try changing `@playlist = @event.playlists.create(:file)` to `@playlist = @event.playlists.create(params[:file])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a hash with parameters to the create action:

```
class Api::V1::PlaylistsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @playlist = @event.playlists.create(
      file: params[:file],
      song: params[:original_filename]
    )
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  end
end
```

It will also set the song property, based on the original filename

Comment: I have edited my post with playlist model and playlist table

Comment: i corrected the example a bit, to also use the original filename as the songname

Comment: I have used your above code, but original_filename is not working. Here is my link to question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594217/how-to-use-parameters-in-rails-controller]